# How do i validate that a Record has been created in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

I have a small Rails application with a database that holds different `Languages`. Each of these `Languages` is subject to change, and i want to keep track of their changes.
I do this by creating an `Audit` record when the object is changed. This `Audit` has a `has_many :languages, through: :audit_language_couplings` field which validates the relationship.

```
class Audit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :audit_type

  has_many :audit_language_couplings
  has_many :languages, through: :audit_language_couplings

  validates_presence_of :audit_type, :admin_id, :date, :before
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :audit_language_couplings
  has_many :audits, through: :audit_language_couplings

  validates_presence_of :iso_code, :display_name, :keyboard_layout, :flag_url, :luis_app_identification, :luis_authorized_key, :luis_location
end
```

The audits are created by calling the `create_audit()` method in the `LanguagesController` when the `PUT`, `DELETE` or `POST` method is called. I also have a `/languages/:id/audits` endpoints that returns all the audits for the given language in JSON.

The `create_token()` method:

```
def create_audit(type, admin_id)
    @language.audits.create(
      audit_type_id: type,
      admin_id: admin_id,
      date: Time.now.to_date,
      before: @language.to_s # TODO: Use the to-be-created to_json() or to_s() method instead.
    )
  end
```

This is also the nature of my problem (i think).
I am currently testing my API with RSpec and Factory bot requests. When i create or update a `Language` in the tests, no `Audits` are being created for some reason. But i know the code works, because it works when i do it manually with postman in my dev environment.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :language do
    iso_code { Faker::Address.country_code }
    display_name { Faker::Address.country }
    keyboard_layout { Faker::Internet.url }
    flag_url { Faker::Internet.url }
    luis_app_identification { Faker::Lorem.characters(5) }
    luis_authorized_key { Faker::Lorem.characters(5) }
    luis_location { Faker::Lorem.characters(5) }
  end
end
```

I have currently structured my tests like this:

```
describe 'POST /admin/language' do
    let(:valid_attributes) do
      {
        payload: {
          iso_code: 'en-US',
          display_name: 'English (US)',
          keyboard_layout: 'QWERTY',
          flag_url: '/public/images/en-US.png',
          luis_app_identification: 'test',
          luis_authorized_key: 'test',
          luis_location: 'test'
        }
      }
    end

    context 'when the request is valid' do
      before { post '/admin/languages', params: valid_attributes, headers: token_header }

      it 'creates a language' do
        expect(json['iso_code']).to eq('en-US')
      end

      it 'returns status code 201' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
      end

      context 'an audit should be made for the change' do
        before { get "/admin/languages/#{language_id}/audits", headers: token_header }

        it 'creates 1 audit' do
          expect(json.size).to eq 1
        end

        it 'is an audit of type 1 [ADD]' do
          expect(json[0]['audit_type_id']).to eq 1
        end
      end
    end

    context 'when the request is invalid' do
      before do
        post '/admin/languages', headers: token_header, params:
          {
            payload: {
              display_name: 'English (US)',
              keyboard_layout: 'QWERTY',
              flag_url: '/public/images/en-US.png',
              luis_app_identification: 'test',
              luis_authorized_key: 'test',
              luis_location: 'test'
            }
          }
      end

      it 'returns status code 422' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(422)
      end

      it 'returns a validation failure message' do
        expect(response.body).to match(/Validation failed: Iso code can't be blank/)
      end
    end
  end
```

The test where i check the audits fails, because 0 audits are returned when running the code with RSpec.

I think i am doing something wrong with the factories, but i am not sure, please let me know!

Cheers

Comment: Where is `create_audit` method called? Could you show the controller code?

Comment: One thing you could do to troubleshoot is to change your create_audit method to do `@language.audits.create!(`. This way you'll see an error in RSpec if the create is failing.

Comment: Why do you think that a many to many association between audit and language is needed here? I would think that its actually one to many (an audit `belongs_to  :language` and a language `has_many :audits`) since you are keeping track of the changes to a single record.

Comment: Seems like you do not have a `language_id` set.

Comment: Thank you Pennypacker, i think i have found the problem, it seems my seeds are not being run on startup. Because it warns me about missing an AuditType in the DB. I Wish someone had told me that trick before. I will attempt to fix this and report back.  

max, because there are also other objects which use `Audit`, so my idea was that audit does not need to have a `Language` or `Answer` or any other record. Not sure if my train of though is correct here.

Comment: Thats not really correct - no. It sounds more like what you want is a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). There are also several gems like papertrail which you might want to look into instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Pennycracker and ReggieB's answers were correct, or actually part of the bigger picture.

The part about the `create!()` shebang lead me to the actual issue. The factories did not create an `AuditType` on which the `Audit` was depending.
ReggieB suggested that my test setup was flawed, because i was testing a nested request.

I have opted to use an altered version of his suggestion, one which better fits my current setup:

```
context 'when the request is valid' do
  before { post '/admin/languages', params: valid_attributes, headers: token_header(admin_id: admin.id) }

  it 'returns status code 201' do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
  end

  context 'the audit system has to be updated' do
    it 'creates 1 audit' do
      expect(Audit.all.size).to eq(1)
    end

    it 'should have type 1 [ADD]' do
      expect(Audit.first.audit_type.id).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

The database cleaner gem cleans the database after each example, so checking for the first `Audit` works the same as expecting a change.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly what's going on based on the code provided, but one thing you can try is changing your `create_audit` method to:

```
def create_audit(type, admin_id)
    @language.audits.create!(
```

Adding the `!` (bang) to the `create` method will raise an exception if for some reason the create fails, which should show up in your RSpec logs. This should at least help you get to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to check is that when the post happens, that the number of `Audit` instances increases by one. I'd do this like this:

```
subject { post '/admin/languages', params: valid_attributes, headers: token_header }
it 'creates an audit'
  expect { subject }.to change { Audit.count }.by(1)
end
```

At the moment you test that there is one audit (without checking how many there were before the spec) and via an indirect method (calling another API endpoint after the first).